# Firebase authentication timeout with Google account login

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

Please can anyone help with config/troubleshooting for Firebase authentication with GAE Python apps.

I've tried to get the Firenotes app working (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine) but when the app loads there's a popup with the error: The operation has timed out. Dismiss.

The email authentication works fine, all OK: can login, save notes, logout.

The problem is with the Google OAuth login.
Clicking on the Google sign button gives an error: 
This site can’t provide a secure connection.
firebaseapp.com didn’t accept your login certificate, or your login certificate may have expired.
ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT

The project was imported into the firebase project and as far as I can tell the config of main.js and app.yaml is correct.
The GAE .appspot.com has been added to the OAuth authorized doamins

The same error is if running local or deployed to GAE.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this following the tutorial. References to 'ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT' seem to indicate a local issue interfering with the TLS negotiation. Were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the 'Overview' section of your firebase console. You can select to "add firebase to your web app". A screen pops up with the config information for the frontend main.js file.

Mind you, the apiKey in the client config needs to be set to the google cloud platform api key for the app engine project your using.

This will enable the login.